# Aggregating an atmospheric gas concentration profile

Tags: computational-physics, atmospheric-science, data-analysis

I have a list of CO2 gas concentrations in the atmosphere in g/g relative to dry air according to a pressure profile. I have the top and bottom pressures for each level.
The list corresponds to a 40 layers atmoshperic model from sea level to pressure = 0.

To simplify things I would like to reduce the number of layers in the model to three for example. How can I derive the CO2 concentrations in the 3 new layers?

Comment: Why do you want to [smooth your data](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smoothing)?

Comment: Your data is probably intended for use in mathematical models that use 3D cells.  Supposedly, an increased number of smaller 3D cells allows a mathematical model to provide a closer match to reality.  Can you provide more details regarding why you want to work with data that is less "granular"?

Comment: Utlimately i'm going to use the full model but running it is computationnaly expensive, therefore for preliminary developpement I would like to use a simplified yet representative model

Comment: I cannot see how a 40-element lookup table would be a significant performance hit in a numerical simulation (I've done much more than that in my simulations without issue). What does your profiler tell you?

Comment: It's not a lookup table it is a radiative transfer model where the radiance Jacobians are computed for each molecule at each layer, which requires lots of computing power

Answer (score 0):

An algorithmic way to "simplify" the curve points is to use the [Ramer-Douglas-Peucker algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ramer%E2%80%93Douglas%E2%80%93Peucker_algorithm), which is an *iterative end point algorithm* that removes pieces of the curve that are within some user-specified epsilon distance from the two end points. A visual representation of the algorithm is seen below, taken from the linked Wikipedia entry.

[image: 1]

The python implementation would be something like,

```
def rdp(x: list, y: list, epsilon: float) -> tuple:
    max_dist, dist_idx = 0, 0
    for i in range(1, len(x)-1):
        # get current perpendicular distance between this index & end-points
        cur_dist = perpendicular_distance(x[0], y[0], x[i], y[i], x[-1], y[-1])
        # if the current distance is larger than existing max, accept the point
        if cur_dist > max_dist:
            max_dist, dist_idx = cur_dist, i

    # if the max distance is above epsilon, recurse on the two points
    if max_dist > epsilon:
        left_x, left_y = rdp(x[:dist_idx+1], y[:dist_idx+1], epsilon)
        right_x, right_y = rdp(x[dist_idx:], y[dist_idx:], epsilon)
        # return the concatenated result
        return concatenate(left_x, right_x), concatenate(left_y, right_y)

    # no recursion necessary, return the first & last points of the two lists
    return [x[0], x[-1]], [y[0], y[-1]]
```

Here, the [perpendicular distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distance_from_a_point_to_a_line#Line_defined_by_two_points) would be,
$$d=\frac{|(x_{-1}-x_0)(y_0-y_i)-(x_0-x_i)(y_{-1}-y_0)|}{\sqrt{(x_{-1}-x_0)^2+(y_{-1}-y_0)^2}}$$
where the subscripts match the indices in the code. The `concatenate` function needs to handle matching the last index of the left and first index of the right points, since these would be the same points.

Note that the larger the value of $\epsilon$, the fewer resulting data points there would be. This method would likely work very well for the purpose of testing, though I would recommend

1. verifying with a [profiler](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Profiling_(computer_programming)) that the portion of your code using the original curve is indeed a significant performance drag (my feeling is this won't be the case)
2. that reducing the curve from ~40 points down to ~3 points won't eliminate valleys/peaks that are important to other parts of the codebase (e.g., returning a pressure of $x$ bar (original curve) results in one function being called but a pressure of $y$ bar (reduced curve) calls a different function).